# What is the fastest way to increment a real-time view count?

Tags: php, mysql, performance

I run a website that has videos on it. I want a per-video view count that should be available to all users at all times.

Normally I'd use something such as:

```
UPDATE videos SET views = views+1 WHERE id = ...
```

Is there any way that's faster and/or better?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That particular way is subject to concurrency errors, unless you are dealing with them using transactions/locks.

I would lean more towards a hit count like:

```
INSERT DELAYED INTO video_hits (video_id, time) VALUES (:video_id, NOW());
```

That way you can get a count, but also get statistics on views over time.

Note: the `DELAYED` is only for MyISAM, which is good because it returns instantly, and `COUNT(*)` is fast on MyISAM tables. You could omit it for InnoDB.

Comment: For future reference, there are two caveates to be aware of: 1) `INSERT DELAYED` doesn't work with `InnoDB` tables so you probably want a separate table just for the view count as Petah has suggested, and 2) queued rows that haven't been `INSERT`ed will be lost if `mysqld` dies unexpectedly or if the table in question is `ALTER`ed.

Comment: @user113215 Added a note about the MyISAM, also your point about `mysqld` is almost invalid, as your server should never die. If it does, you have bigger problems.

Comment: Not entirely an invalid point... that's what [atomicity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID#Atomicity) is all about!

Answer (score 1):

Yep. Use Memcached.
http://www.php.net/manual/en/memcached.increment.php

Then write a cron script that will write the changed values to the table once in a while, just in case. I don't think view count is a particularly important info - losing a few minutes of data in case of a server crash should be fine.

Redis is an option, too, although it's harder to set up. As a bonus you'd get persistence and sorted sets, so no need to involve MySQL at all.

If you really need to use MySQL with InnoDB, your only option is to fiddle with `innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit`, but that's kind of dangerous. MyISAM won't work at all (it locks the entire table for every write).